# Advantages of Importing Stylesheets vs. Linking in HTML?

Tags: css, web-frontend

Does the CSS import keyword prevent additional server requests by locally accessing or fetching imported stylesheets on the web server during a single request to the linked stylesheet? Or is it primarily intended for modularity, providing a single point for modification (linked stylesheet)?

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be conflating a few different things here.

In Sass/SCSS, `@import` is used to add additional programmatic resources to a Sass file/context and/or to bundle together additional styles.  This is all done at compilation time, so there will be a single bundled file to be delivered to the browser, with no additional HTTP calls necessary (for CSS).  From the [Sass `@import` reference page](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/import):

> Sass extends CSS's `@import` rule with the ability to import Sass and CSS stylesheets, providing access to mixins, functions, and variables and combining multiple stylesheets' CSS together. Unlike plain CSS imports, which require the browser to make multiple HTTP requests as it renders your page, Sass imports are handled entirely during compilation.

*(Also, it is deprecated and slated for removal, intended to be replaced by the [`@use` rule](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/use).)*

In CSS, `@import` behaves by making additional HTTP requests to fetch and load additional CSS files asynchronously and as needed.  From the [MDN CSS `@import` reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@import):

> The `@import` CSS at-rule is used to import style rules from other style sheets.
> ...
> **So that user agents can avoid retrieving resources for unsupported media types, authors may specify media-dependent `@import` rules.** These conditional imports specify comma-separated media queries after the URL. In the absence of any media query, the import is unconditional. Specifying all for the medium has the same effect.

Critically, this type of dynamic fetching based on browser support could *only* be done in each individual browser, not precompiled.

From your question, you write:

> ...does it prevent multiple link tags in a single html file?

I'm not sure either instance does what you are suggesting.  I do think that sometimes in a development mode, your bundling process may opt to just inject several `<style/>` blocks or `<link/>` elements rather than bundling all the CSS.  I suppose logically in both Sass and CSS contexts the `@import` is technically replacing or otherwise preventing the need for several `<link/>` elements from being added, but that is a bit of a simplification of how/why they are used.

Comment: Glad this helped-- please remember to mark as your selected answer and upvote if you have sufficient privilege.  Happy coding!